# php custom session handler -- write + close functions do NOT have access to global connection variable

Tags: php

I am modifying http://phpsecurity.org/code/ch08-2 to use mysqli functions and am running into an odd issue where the `_write` function doesn't have access to database. The errors are below. It appears somehow the `$_sess_db` variable is not available in _write + _close functions. I have verified the connection is available in the read function.

NOTE: I can get this to work if I re-connect to database in _write + _close functions; but this is not ideal as it should just be opened once in the _open function.

ALSO: I know global variables are NOT the best solution; but please leave comments and answers only to this question.

ERRORS:

```
Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phppos/resellers_session.php on line 47

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phppos/resellers_session.php on line 48

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phppos/resellers_session.php on line 49

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phppos/resellers_session.php on line 54

Warning: mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/phppos/resellers_session.php on line 17
```

CODE:

```
<?php
session_set_save_handler('_open', '_close', '_read', '_write', '_destroy', '_clean');
session_start();

function _open()
{
    global $_sess_db;
    $_sess_db = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DBNAME);
     return TRUE;
}

//CANNOT CONNECT TO DATABASE
function _close()
{
    global $_sess_db;

    return mysqli_close($_sess_db);
}

//CANNOT CONNECT TO DATABASE
function _write($id, $data)
{   
    global $_sess_db;
    $access = time();

    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($_sess_db, $id);
    $access = mysqli_real_escape_string($_sess_db,$access);
    $data = mysqli_real_escape_string($_sess_db, $data);

    $sql = "REPLACE 
            INTO sessions
            VALUES  ('$id', '$access', '$data')";
    return mysqli_query($_sess_db, $sql);
}
```

Comment: Global variable? Yre you seroius using these dangerous feature?

Comment: As I said in my question; I am not interested in hearing about global variable issues. I understand the risks

Comment: Sorry. Then there is no place to talk about the solution.

Comment: Well... have you initialised `$_sess_db`...? Certainly not in the code you're showing.

Comment: In the _open function I have. As I said in question it is avialble in _read function

Comment: I am not sure why I got all the down votes. I clearly stated the question with code + errors and even got the correct solution..

Comment: @ChrisMuench To be fair to the downvoters you question wasn't the clearest - if you'd cut out all the MySQL parts of the code you'd have discovered that the problem still exists, have a really short bit of code to post, and been half-way to the solution by yourself.

Comment: The database part was necessary because the problem itself was not connecting to the database. in the _write + _close functions. I also added NOTE: I can get this to work if I re-connect to database in _write + _close functions; but this is not ideal as it should just be opened once in the _open function. I am not sure what else I could have done.

Comment: I agree with you on one point that it might have been too much code. I have cleaned it up so it is clearer to other people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the code you've shown you are not explicitly calling `session_write_close()`, instead waiting for PHP to do an implicit close and write of the session in the script shutdown phase. Unfortunately for you this implicit action occurs out of the scope of your global variables - hence the `null`s.

If you insist on using globals something like the following should work for you:

```
register_shutdown_function('shutdown');

function shutdown()
{
    session_write_close();
}
```

I'd think carefully about using your custom session handler - what you've got there is not robust and although it might seem to work correctly under some light testing you could end up with a serious headache down the line if you don't fully understand what's going on.

Comment: Ah ok...I didn't realize that would happen. This is for a very low traffic art of my site. I need to use databases for this part of the site due to load balancer.

I ended up doing `register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');` to make it shorter.